# Find splitting field of $x^5-4x+2$ over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: polynomials, galois-theory

I know how to get the splitting field from the roots but I just can't come up with any factorisation that gives me roots. Any suggestions?

Comment: this http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=factor+x%5E5-4x%2B2 might help

Comment: This is irreducible by Eisenstein with p=2 isn't it?

Comment: Once we know that this polynomial has no $\Bbb Q$-factorization and no way of expressing the roots by means of radicals and roots of unity, it’s hard to know what form a satisfactory answer to this question could take.

Answer (score 9):

It is quite difficult to find explicitly the splitting field. The Extension is not solvable.

In fact the Galois group of the splitting field of 
$$ f(x)=x^5-4x+2$$
is isomorphic to $S_5$.

This is because the polynomial has exactly two complex roots (Study the graph of the function to determine it), hence the complex conjugation acts on the set of roots as a transposition.

Moreover, since $5$ divides the order of the group, there exist a $5$-cycle.

So the Galois group $G$ is a subgroup of $S_5$ generated by a transposition and a $5$-cycle. Since $5$ is prime this means that $G=S_5$ (If $p$ is a prime number, a transposition and a $p$-cycle always generate $S_p$).

So you can not express the roots of the polynomial $f$ by radicals, but at least you can say that the degree of the extension is $5!$.

Comment: Also note that through perturbation theory you can use (x + e)^5, expand it binomially and equate coefficients of the powers series for x^5 radius of convergence. That should provide you with the missing 4 kernels of S5.