# Galois group of $x^5-4x^4 + 2$ over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: galois-theory

I'm trying to read someone's proof that the polynomial $f(x) = x^5 - 4x^4 + 2$ is not solvable by radicals. They do this by showing that the Galois group is $S_5$.

The derivative is $5x^4 - 16x^3 = x^3(5x-15)$, so the roots of $f'(x)$ are zero and $16/5$. From this the proof concludes that $f(x)$ has at most three real roots and has two complex roots. What does that conclusion follow from?

Additionally, the proof says that 5 must divide the order of the Galois group. Someone in an answer to [Find splitting field of $x^5-4x+2$ over $\mathbb{Q}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1541127/find-splitting-field-of-x5-4x2-over-mathbbq) also concludes this (without any explanation that I can see). Why does 5 divide the order of the Galois group?

Comment: To have four real roots, the graph of $f$ must cross the $x$-axis at least four times, so how many local max/mins must you at least have? (And your polynomial has no repeated roots since it doesn't share any with it's derivative)

Comment: It would need to have at least four local maxima or minima. But $f$ can have no more than 2 local extrema since $f'$ only vanishes at two points.

Answer (score 1):

Question 1: By [Rolle's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolle%27s_theorem), between two distinct real roots of $f$ there must be some root of $f'$. So $f$ has at most one real root more than $f'$. Since $f'$ has at two real roots, $f$ has at most three real roots. By the [fundamental theorem of algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_algebra), $f$ has exactly $5$ roots in $\mathbb C$. Since at most three of them are real, the remaining two must be non-real.

Question 2 : That's because, by Galois theory, the order of the Galois group is the same thing as $[{\mathbb L}:{\mathbb Q}]$ where $\mathbb L$ is the splitting field. Now, if $\alpha$ is any root of $f(x)$, you have $[{\mathbb L}:{\mathbb Q}]=[{\mathbb L}:{\mathbb Q}(\alpha)][{\mathbb Q}(\alpha):{\mathbb Q}]$, and ${\mathbb Q}(\alpha):{\mathbb Q}]=5$ because $f$ is irreducible with degree $5$.

Comment: Thank you. What about the question regarding the derivative and having complex roots?

Comment: @JoshuaRuiter Please see my update