# Solubility by Radicals

Tags: galois-theory

I am trying to show that $f(t)=t^{5}-4t^{2}+2$ is not soluble by radicals over $\mathbb{Q}$.

I think I need to show that $\text{Gal}(f)$ is not soluble. I think I need to construct an embedding $\text{Gal}(f)\hookrightarrow A_{5}$ which is not soluble since the commutator subgroup of $A_{5}$ is $A_{5}$. So how do I do this?

Comment: See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2262318/galois-group-of-x5-4x4-2-over-mathbbq?noredirect=1&lq=1); similarly $x^5-4x^2+2$.

Comment: As my droll algebra prof noted, those are polynomials that dissolve in water.

Comment: @user4894: That's solubility by ions!

Answer (score 0):

Use some elementary calculus and you shall see $f$ has exactly two non real roots. So the Galois group of $f$ contains a transposition (taking complex root to it's conjugate) and also a 5 cycle (since $5$ divides $|Gal(f)| $ and $ Gal(f) $ is a subgroup of $S_5$. But $S_5$ is generated by a transposition and a 5 cycle. So we have $Gal(f)=S_5$ and hence not solvable.